# How to kill and rerun process in one command in Linux

Tags: ps, process-management

Usually, I use the `ps` command on Linux to find the pid of the process, then I kill the process using this pid and after that I rerun the process with some specific command for this specific process.

My question is - how can I kill and rerun the process in single command?

Is it possible?

Comment: Some programs listen to a Hangup signal to reload their config files. You can send a SIGHUP by running kill with the -HUP (or -1) argument: `kill -HUP 1234` - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGHUP

Answer (score 2):

You could get the PID and then read the `/prc/$pid/cmdline` file to see the command used to launch it:

```
pid=123
com=$(perl -pe 's/\0/ /g' /proc/$pid/cmdline)
kill 123 && "$com"
```

So you could turn that into a function:

```
restartPid(){
    pid=$1
    com=$(perl -pe 's/\0/ /g' /proc/"$pid"/cmdline)
    kill 123 && "$com"
}
```

However, this will not work for more complex cases where a command was run with a specific environment. You could start getting more creating and extend this to also include the environment with something like this:

```
restartPid(){
  pid=$1
  tempFile=$(mktemp)
  perl -pe 's/\0/\n/g' /proc/"$pid"/environ |
    perl -pe 's/^([^=]+)=(.*)/$1="$2"/' > "$tempFile"
  read -r com args < <(perl -lne '@k=split(/\0/); print "$k[0] ",  join " ", map "\"$_\"", @k[1..$#k]' /proc/"$pid"/cmdline)
    dir=$(readlink -f "/proc/$pid/cwd")    
    kill $pid
    ( . \"$tempFile\"; cd "$dir"; eval $com $args )
}
```

However this is getting quite complex, as you can see, and I cannot guarantee it will always work. Should be a good start though.

Comment: Might also be worth a `cd /proc/"$pid"/cwd` to start in the same working directory